# Rails new Object with Params from the Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an model called Order and i want initiate with some params like below

```
@order = Order.new(user_id: current_user.id, type_of_order: 'events', order_date: DateTime.now)
```

i get the error

> undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Is there an easy to to mass assign there parameters than having to do something like

```
@order[:order_date] = DateTime.now
@order[user_id] = current_user.id
```

Comment: It says, `current_user` is `nil`, means user has not logged in. It is NOT mass assign issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the error you are getting is due to the fact that your
`current_user` variable is `nil`. I guess you don't want to have an order without a user, so you should revise your code's logic to avoid that.

Second, if you want to be able to mass-assign parameters you have to specify in the controller creating or modifying the object which parameters can be assigned at once:

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)

...

private
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:order_date, :user_id)
end
```

Comment: In Rails 4, `attr_accessible` has been moved from model to the controller and is called [strong parameters](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/)

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the ror 4 tag, and still using 3.2, I'll edit.